# is there any way to save my object on a DB and then when I get it back ready it normally?

Tags: java

I am making some project on Java.... I need to save a huge amount of data into different tables... but all in one submit, so, for make it easy to control I created a dto and I defined my object... until here is great, now I want to save it I was wondering if I can serialize it and save it, or in some way save it on my database (using a new table) and save the object as itself (instead create fields for every attribute and save each one), and then, get all the object back and be able to use all the info.

there is any way? I was searching about save serialized objects and the get them back, any idea if this is the way?

p.d. I am using JPA and spring

Comment: Use Hibernate? What is a huge amount of data?

Comment: huge amount of data i mean is a form taht has 150 fields... and are divided into 4 tables... according my criteria (i didnt design it, but i dont have time to re design all)... and instead separate and save on diff tables i want to save my entire object

Comment: If you are using JPA, it already gives you your object back..although it still creates all of the fields in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

http://javapapers.com/core-java/serialize-de-serialize-java-object-from-database/

otherwise use some of the Object-Relational mechanisms:

http://www.hibernate.org

http://blog.mybatis.org

Comment: i had checked taht link, i think its a good solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JPA, as you stated you are, then you will get your object back if you do a `find` or a [createQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13189_01/kodo/docs40/full/html/ejb3_overview_query.html):

```
public static MyObject findMyObject( String id ) {
    MyObject.PK pk = new MyObject.PK( id );
    MyObject result = entityManager.find( MyObject.class, pk );
    return result;    
}
```

This will work if you have an entity object defined called `MyObject`.